# What does Starkware Industries mean?

Tags: terminology, zero-knowledge

What does **Starkware** Industries mean? Is it related to **Zcash** company?

Its name apparently comes from **Zero Knowledge Stark (zk-STARKs)**.

I appreciate it if someone could define **Starkware** Industries in some lines?

Answer (score 1):

According to this article: (https://medium.com/coinmonks/zk-starks-create-verifiable-trust-even-against-quantum-computers-dd9c6a2bb13d)

> *"There is a new company called StarkWare Industries that is looking to
>   solve some of the challenges with leveraging ZK-S**T**ARKs (one being the
>   size of the proof) and also commercialize the technology, which can be
>   leveraged across multiple industries, including blockchain
>   implementations."*

So, it's related to employing S**T**ARKs in the blockchain.